# Find the value of limit satisfying the given condition

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)= \cos(x/2)\cdot\cos(x/4)\cdots\cos(x/2^n)$.If lim $ \lim_{n \to infinity}  f(x) =g(x)$ , such that $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=k$, then the value of $\lim_{k \to 1} (1-k^{2011})/(1-k)$

[image: My Work]

I want to know that my solution is correct or not. If it incorrect please tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the OP.

Letting $\theta=x/2^{k}$ in the double-angle formula $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ reveals

$$\cos(x/2^{k})=\frac{\sin(x/2^{k-1})}{2\sin(x/{2^k})} \tag 1$$

for $x\ne 0$.

Then, using $(1)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
f_n(x)&=\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(x/2^{k})\\\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(x/2^{k-1})}{2\sin(x/{2^k})}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{2^n \sin(x/2^{n})}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

for $x\ne 0$ with $f_n(0)=1$.  Then, taking the limit we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

for all $x$.  If we designate the limit by $g(x)$, then clearly $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ for all $x\ne 0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=1$.

On a seemingly unrelated limit, we see that

$$\frac{1-k^{2011}}{1-k}=\sum_{n=0}^{2010} k^n$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to 1} \left(\frac{1-k^{2011}}{1-k}\right)&=\lim_{k\to 1}\sum_{n=0}^{2010} k^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2010} (1)\\\\
&=2011
\end{align}$$

Comment: How you preform summation part , can we also use l hopital there ?

Comment: Note that we are summing a geometric progression.  And L'Hospital's Rule is applicable and works well here.

Comment: Yo have taken sum of 2001 terms

Comment: @user346279 Good catch!  That was a typographical error.

Comment: I think you have inadvertently made a typo. The limit of $f_{n}(x)$ is not $1$ but $(\sin x)/x = g(x)$ and hence $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = 1 = k$. The last limit involves $k$ and is completely disconnected from the rest of the question and you are right about that.

Comment: @paramanandsingh Thanks for catching that.  I've edited.